# Possible to store function call order in a list?

Tags: java

I have a class that builds a string by successively calling functions.

```
private String mString;
addFoo();
addBar();
addBaz();
```

However, in an RTL environment, I need to build the string in reverse, i.e. the function call order should be:

```
addBaz();
addBar();
addFoo();
```

Is it possible to store this call order in a list, so that I can just traverse it in reverse when in RTL environment? I am trying to avoid duplicating the flow, since I know it's going to be exactly reversed. Is there a better solution than the one I'm thinking of?

Comment: Note that simple word reversal won't work because there are different types of formatting and spans applied to the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an interface such as

```
public interface Action {
     public void performAction();
}
```

and store a `List<Action>`. Then, just iterate the list in reverse order. You can also use a `Deque<Action>` : you first push the actions, and then pop them until the deque is empty. Choose that solution if you don't need to keep track of the actions after executing them in reverse. Otherwise, use a `LinkedList` for better performances.

If you use Java 8 and have just a few different actions, you can define them with lambda expressions. For example :

```
 Action a = () -> System.out.println("Hello world");
```

If you use Java 7 or less, use anonymous classes :

```
 Action a = new Action() {
      @Override
      public void performAction() {
           System.out.println("Hello world");
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `enum`.

```
 public enum FunctionCalls{
       ADDFOO,ADDBAR,ADDBAZ;
 }
```

and then define a `List<FunctionCalls>`, then iterate over the list forward or backward and `switch` with the cases being your function calls.

```
 switch(functionCall){
       case ADDFOO: addFoo();
       case ADDBAR: addBar();
       case ADDBAZ: addBaz();
 }
```

Comment: Not very reusable and evolutive. What if he has a hundred different actions to perform ?

Comment: then index them as numbers? Idk you can do this without either reflection (not very safe for a user app) or defining something like this

Comment: An interface is actually much better here